# Why dereference is not necessary here?

Tags: perl

```
my $arr = [[2,4],[1,3]];
print $$arr[0]->[1];
```

It prints 1 as expected.

If I remove the dereference:

```
my $arr = [[2,4],[1,3]];
print $$arr[0][1];
```

It still works and no warning at all? Why?

Comment: Check out the Arrow Rule section in perlreftut.

Comment: `$arr->[0][1]` would be clearest

Comment: The answer is, of course, "because Perl is awesome."

Comment: @ikegami I like your solution :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dereference is always assumed between any `{}` and `[]`.  The following are identical:

```
print $var[2]{key}[3][5];
```

and

```
print $var[2]->{key}->[3]->[5];
```

From the docs

[`perlreftut #Arrow Rule`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html#Arrow-Rule)

> In between two **subscripts**, the arrow is optional.
>
> Instead of `$a[1]->[2]`, we can write `$a[1][2]` ; it means the same thing. Instead of `$a[0]->[1] = 23` , we can write `$a[0][1] = 23` ; it means the same thing.
>
> Now it really looks like two-dimensional arrays!
>
> You can see why the arrows are important. Without them, we would have had to write `${$a[1]}[2]` instead of `$a[1][2]` . For three-dimensional arrays, they let us write `$x[2][3][5]` instead of the unreadable `${${$x[2]}[3]}[5]` .

[`perlref #Using References`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References), section 3:

> The arrow is optional *between* brackets subscripts